# Camera on the ground vs camera in a train

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

A couple days ago my history teacher was explaining special relativity with the train example, where you are in a train close to light speed and you see a clock on the train terminal and the clock goes faster. And my teacher said that if you saw a person on the terminal that person will age faster. But what would happen if you put one camera on the train and one on the ground both facing at that person and in the same exact place the camera on the train and the camera on the ground take a picture. Will the person in the train picture look older than the person in the ground picture?

Comment: What do you mean my "in the exact same place"? If you are trying to let both pictures be taken "simultaneously", then the whole *point* of relativity is that that is somewhat ill-defined or *relative*.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it sounds like OP proposes 2 cameras: one on the train, pointing outwards toward the platform, and one by the side of the rail, also pointing towards the platform. Both take a photograph of someone on the platform at the exact moment the train goes past. If that's what you're asking, OP, both photos look the same.

(Assuming the cameras have really fast shutters so the first doesn't have awful motion blur, of course...)

Comment: Just one clarification: it is the opposite, the person in the train will watch the clocks on the stations run slower, and people age slower too.

Comment: @brucesmitherson. I'm  sure it is the way I posted it because the light from the clock is reaching the train very quickly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox

Answer (score 0):

The cameras are at the same place, because we ignore the small distance between the cameras, right?

When the cameras are at the same place, then the same information arrives at the same time at both cameras.

The person in the train picture will look the same age as the person in the ground picture.